# How can I create a TypeScript type for a constructor with one argument of a specified type and the rest of the arguments unspecified?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a type which guarantees that a class receives a particular type as the first argument to its constructor. Given these definitions,

```js
export type UnaryConstructor<Item, Options> = new (
  options: Options,
  ...args: any[]
) => Item;

class AnItemOptions {}

class SomethingElse {}
```

I'd like

```js
const item: UnaryConstructor<AnItem, AnItemOptions> = AnItem;
```

to typecheck properly for

```js
// good
class AnItem {
  constructor(options: AnItemOptions, somethingElse: SomethingElse);
}
```

and to fail to typecheck for any of these where the `AnItemOptions` argument is missing or the order is mixed up:

```js
// bad!
class AnItem {
  constructor(somethingElse: SomethingElse, options: AnItemOptions);
}

class AnItem {
  constructor(somethingElse: SomethingElse);
}
```

However, both of the above statements pass typechecking!

When I try to define `UnaryConstructor` with `args` absent, or with type `unknown[]` or `Object[]`, I get different errors.

However, this pattern works with normal functions. If I write:

```js
type UnaryFunction<Item, Options> = (options: Options, ...args[]) => Item;
```

Then, as I expect,

```js
// good! typechecks
const fn: UnaryFunction<Item, Options> = (options: Options, somethingElse: SomethingElse) => { return new Item(options, somethingElse); }
```

typechecks, whereas the same function with the order of arguments reversed

```js
// bad! does not typecheck
const fn: UnaryFunction<Item, Options> = (somethingElse: SomethingElse, options: Options) => { return new Item(options, somethingElse); }
```

does not typecheck.

Any ideas why typechecking seems to break only on constructors?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. `AnItemOptions` and `SomethingElse` are *structurally identical* since they are just empty interfaces. Without any differentiating structure, they can be used interchangeably.

Fill up the interfaces to see it working correctly.

```
interface IModuleProperties {
    name: string;
}

interface IModuleState {
    index: number;
}

class AnItem1 {
  constructor(options: AnItemOptions, somethingElse: SomethingElse) {}
}

class AnItem2 {
  constructor(somethingElse: SomethingElse, options: AnItemOptions) {}
}

class AnItem3 {
  constructor(somethingElse: SomethingElse) {}
}
```

```
const item1: UnaryConstructor<AnItem1, AnItemOptions> = AnItem1;

// error
const item2: UnaryConstructor<AnItem2, AnItemOptions> = AnItem2;
const item3: UnaryConstructor<AnItem3, AnItemOptions> = AnItem3;
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqA7AhlRBhCDAZxigFcBjGaAHgEkZgBbAGjgHkwYBLQogPjgBeOBmAB3OAAoAUHDgQuvYgC4OSvizlwAdHpwBzImqwZEAbQC6MgJTDBDZgG4ZMigBssRInACCGRyZOHj44AG9teSwAQjUSKG4MAxkAX1cPLx8AZQgmYBgAC0SDAFF3IlQI+XkAI1jRMiYa4ChU9M9vPwDGJgBGcO0KPlJKaigpRRDVLsDg5SI2Ilz8oqSyirUcvMLi9eA7MLS0tw6ff0CAJgH5IeIRqmgpJe3V0vLgTeWdtfe2Sfm1OcenM+Acju1MjMegBma5wW7xUaPZ4rXbvT4vNEVMFtdLDODcHq9NSYHD4YbkB5QGhA5i9Ni0oIaYiCESM3ouBHwQnMC4k7C4Ah3SljGndXkM8VMqYCYRQ3mc-E8pjQ-lkoWIqliwLQyWzZmytlS6EuIA)